# Syncing skydrive files

Tags: onedrive

I am writing an ios application which needs to sync the user's skydrive files and folders. I can not find any REST API to get the changes of user's files and folders. Without this how can I do this sync? If I got user's drive snapshot at t1, then at another time t2, I want to know which files are added/modified/deleted. I am unable to find out how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this topic can help you. You can sync files by uploading files with the LiveUploadOverWriteOption as LiveUploadOverwrite. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659728.aspx#update_files